# How can I express this Constraint?

Tags: haskell, constraint-kinds

I would like to express a `Constraint` on types of kind `k -> k -> Type`, which can be stated in English as:

> A type `s` such that, forall `x` `x'`, `y`, and `y'` where `Coercible x x'` and `Coercible y y'`, `Coercible (s x y) (s x' y')`

Or in even plainer English:

> A type `s` that is always coercible if its two parameters are coercible.

The latter seems tantalizingly close to haskell already, and I have some code that really looks like it should do it:

```
type Representational2 (s :: k -> k -> Type) =
  forall x x' y y'. (Coercible x x', Coercible y y') => Coercible (s x y) (s x' y')
```

However this doesn't work, ghc wants `Coercible (s x y) (s x' y')` to be a type but it is a `Constraint` (`ConstraintKinds` and `QuantifiedConstraints` are on).

```
• Expected a type, but
  ‘Coercible (s x y) (s x' y')’ has kind
  ‘Constraint’
• In the type ‘forall x x' y y'.
               (Coercible x x', Coercible y y') => Coercible (s x y) (s x' y')’
  In the type declaration for ‘Representational2’
```

I don't fully understand what is going on but I gather that ghc does not like a `Constraint` being on the right hand side of `=>` within a `type`. Since I can create type aliases with `Constraint` kinds and I can create `type` aliases with `=>`, no problem.

What is the issue and how can I express this contraint to ghc in a manner it accepts?

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, PolyKinds, RankNTypes, QuantifiedConstraints #-}

import Data.Kind
import Data.Coerce

type Representational2 (s :: k -> k -> Type) =
  forall x x' y y'. (Coercible x x', Coercible y y') => Coercible (s x y) (s x' y') :: Constraint
```

All I did was add `:: Constraint` to your type. Since GHC already knew the kind of the RHS was `Constraint` (due to the error message), I don't really have a good explanation for why this makes it work.

---

Edit: I have a partial explanation: by adding that kind signature to the RHS, your type synonym now has a CUSK (see [the GHC wiki](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/ghc-kinds/kind-inference/)):

> - A type synonym has a CUSK if and only if all of its type variables and its RHS are annotated with kinds.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful and I can move forward, but I am *really* curious as to why this helps at all.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic I found a partial explanation.